# What is the encoding format for unconditional Jumps on SPARC/SPARC64?

Tags: assembly, encoding, compiler-construction, sparc

I am trying to figure out the encoding for unconditional JMPs on SPARC, i.e the JMP. After disassembling a few binaries.

In my IDA disassembly the encoding for JMP %g1 is:

```
81 c0 40 00
```

And the encoding for jmp %g4 is:

```
81 c1 00 00
```

Digging through the spark manuals, I can't seem to find a record of how this is encoded. I am also confused as to why IDA refers to a "JMP" as opposed to the "JMPL" in the docs.

The JMPL encoding recommendations given in the SPARC9 manual are a little arcane to me and I struggle with what they are getting at:

```
10-RD-OP3-RS1-i-[-]-rs2
```

or

```
10-RD-OP3-RS1-i-siMM3
```

"If either of the low-order two bits of the jump address is nonzero, a mem_address_not_aligned
exception occurs"

Well, I'm not sure how that squares with the instruction that IDA found. Can someone break down how this maps to JMP %g1? How would this change for JMP %g2?

Note: This is report for reverse engineering stack exchange, I'm going to delete whichever one gets a good answer first. I've had better luck with this kind of question on SO lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jmp` is an alias for `jmpl` with a destination register of `%g0`, ie. address discarded. The manual specifies that `OP3` is fixed at `11 1000`. The `i` bit selects between the two encoding variants. The single register operand can be encoded in either way, your example uses `i=0` meaning it's the `jmpl %rs1+%rs2, %g0` form. We can now easily produce the machine code:

```
10 (fixed)
00000 (rd=%g0)
11 1000 (OP3, fixed)
00001 (rs1=%g1)
0 (i)
00000000 (ignored)
00000 (rs2=%g0)
```

Concatenating all of these gives `1000 0001 1100 0000 0100 0000 0000 0000 = 81 C0 40 00`

You could also encode `jmp %g1` as `jmp %g1+0` which would use the other variant, with `i=1`, and produces `81 C0 60 00`. Another possibility is `jmp %g0+%g1` which gives `81 C0 00 01`.

To get `jmp %g2` you obviously change the `rs1` field.

Comment: Are the rs1 values successive i.e is RS1 00010 and so on? (edited)

Comment: `00011` is `%g3` ... `rs2` is the placeholder for the other register.

Comment: ^ yeah I edited what I meant there. Thanks for getting back to me!